# Get scanner to include but ignore quoted text?

Tags: java, regex, quotes, java.util.scanner

Basically my problem is this, I need to parse text where `,` is the delimiter but anything in `" "` quotes should not be checked for a delimiter. Is this what the `Scanner.skip` method is for? I would check it myself but I don't understand how to write a regex pattern in java where the token is something in between two `" "`. I also want to include any quoted text in the proper token which was delimited by the valid `,`.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to parse a CSV file, look for any CSV library like http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/ or similar.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into this problem a while ago and didn't find a sufficiently fast solution.

As a result, I incorporated a simple custom String splitter (which ignores delimiters between quotes) into an open source project I work on:

[QuoteAwareStringSplitter.java](https://gist.github.com/2393982)

For example:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
    String s = "ads,asdas,das,das, \"ahda,asd,as,d,a\", adsa";
    String[] tokens = QuoteAwareStringSplitter.splitLine( s );
    for ( String token : tokens )
    {
        System.out.println( token );
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
ads
asdas
das
das
ahda,asd,as,d,a
 adsa
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do this that didn't involve going char by char manually but if it is I guess a solution like this isn't too bad.

Comment: At some point it must be char by char. And it's abstracted from your code when you use something like `QuoteIgnorringStringSplitter`.

Comment: Well, whatever library or solution you choose, even a regular expression based solution, will be setting through `char` by `char` as part of its implementation. It'll just be hidden from you. Regular expressions aren't magic... Edit: @DerMike beat me to it :)

Comment: Certainly, but I was just under the impression there was a way to solve this with a higher level of abstraction within in the standard java library.